# npm uninstall gives no error, but also doesn't remove package?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I want to remove package `@rollup/plugin-graphql@1.1.0` but npm uninstall simply doesn't remove it:

Check installed packages:

```
npm list --depth=0
├── @apollo/client@3.5.8
├── @rollup/plugin-graphql@1.1.0
// some more packages
```

Remove package:

```
npm uninstall @rollup/plugin-graphql@1.1.0

up to date, audited 334 packages in 1s

53 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

Check installed packages again:

```
npm list --depth=0
├── @apollo/client@3.5.8
├── @rollup/plugin-graphql@1.1.0 // <-- still here!
// some more packages
```

What's going on here? `packages.json` also doesn't get changed.

I am on npm 8.3.0, node 16.13.1

Comment: Have you tried simply `npm uninstall @rollup/plugin-graphql`? When uninstalling you don't need the version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this package is a dependency of another package that you have installed ?
If so, since it is still needed, npm doesn't remove it ?

You may investigate with `npm list @rollup/plugin-graphql`